# VS2010 and VS2008 together in a Team

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, team-project, svn

I'm in a team that all members have VS2008 installed on their machine, we have tortois svn as source control system.
Is there a solution that I can work with them with VS2010 installed on my machine? Or I have to install VS2008 to work with the other members?
thanks.

Comment: why not simply install VS2008 side-by-side on your machine? Simple is best...

Comment: I want to just install VS2010 cause this was simpler ;), but I finally installed both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use VS2008 to work with VS2008 projects.

Answer (score 1):

Different members of the team can use different versions of Visual Studio and still target the same .csproj projects.  Unfortunately, they'll need different .sln files -- 2 character difference and Visual Studio freaks out.  See http://robrich.org/archive/2010/04/20/working-with-both-vs-2010-and-2008-on-the-team.aspx for a working example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hearing that VS2010 and VS2008 don't play nicely in terms of project files, but I know I've been able to open some projects in VS2010 and then again in VS2008 (custom .proj files though, so YMMV).  As with all successive versions of Visual Studio, you're probably going to need separate solution files for the two though, and each solution can just include the same projects, e.g.:

```
Foo.csproj
Foo.VS2010.sln (contains Foo.csproj)
Foo.VS2008.sln (contains Foo.csproj)
```

It's also possible that VS2010 will add some junk to the project file by default which makes VS2008 choke a little, but you can always edit the project file manually to clear it out.  I'd recommend giving it a shot with a sample project and see how well the compat works out.

Comment: don't do that, that's unsupported and you will shoot yourself in the foot

Comment: depends on the language: for C++, the original vcproj remains untouched, and it VS2010 creates a cproj for it. So in theory you could use both, but you'd still shoot yourself in the foot when the other team members make changes to just one of the projects.